# java understanding bitwise manipulation

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Recently I have been learning about bitwise operators and along the way there is this code that finds the binary digits of a decimal number using the AND(&) bitwise operator, the code is as follows:

```
 byte b = -34;

 for(int t = 128;t > 0; t = t/2)
{
 if((b & t) != 0)System.out.println("1 ");
 else System.out.println("0 ");
 System.out.println("b & t yields: " + (b & t));
   }
```

I have modified the code to show the value calculated by b&t during each iteration. I would like to understand the exact mechanism behind this code as to why it works to find the binary digits, please explain why is b compared to t each iteration and why is t divided by 2 each iteration?

In addition, I would like to know how is (b&t) calculated manually by listing the binary digits.I do have an understanding how & works but when I listed out the binary digits of 34 and 128 and compared them:

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0(128)
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0(34) //I am unsure if the negative sign should be included
---------------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

the result I got was 0, however the program returns 128 which is perplexing.

Below I will also include the result of the execution of the program:

```
1 
b & t yields: 128
1 
b & t yields: 64
0 
b & t yields: 0
1 
b & t yields: 16
1 
b & t yields: 8
1 
b & t yields: 4
1 
b & t yields: 2
0 
b & t yields: 0
```

Much obliged for the help :)

Comment: Nowadays computers use two's complement, so `-34` is represented by `256-34` as a unsigned byte.

Comment: Thanks very much,it makes sense that -34&128 return 128 now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dividing `t` by `2` is a bit-shift to the right:

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 128 = t
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 64  = t / 2
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 32  = t / 2 / 2
...
```

`t` always has one bit set to `1`, all others are `0`.

Then you compare that to b using `&`. Each result bit is `1` if and only if the corresponding bit in both inputs is `1` as well. 
That means that we basically check if the bit in `b` is `1` at the location that the `t`-bit is `1`. That is done for all bits from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Since there were two questions: 
(1) OP is perplex why his hand-calculation does not match with program's code and
(2) OP would like to know why one of the variables is divided by 2.

I merely combine the answers: 
(1) Negative numbers are represented as two's complement. Therefore negative 34 is

```
 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 <-- +34
 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 <-- one's complement of 34
 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 <-- two's complement of 34
```

Note: two's complement is one's complement + 1.

(2) Division by 2 is shifting to the right (if it is binary). That's why, the third time in the loop, it outputs zero (The only 1 in 128 is 'AND'ed with the third zero in -34).